# PHP & stress tests - load large file into memory

Tags: php

I have to stress test an URL (PHP script) using Apache Benchmark. But for each request, I need a different set of data to be processed, and the URL to remain the same. So inside that PHP script I need to read a 3.000.000 lines file and pick a random one. It means that for each ab request, I need to read that file, then get a random line, then process it.

What method do you recommend?

I was thinking to somehow load that file in memory once (and be available for all requests) and then get a random line from it.

In other words, I need to read one random line from a large file without "feeling" it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the point of the test to load this file into memory? Or is the point to get a random entry from the file which you then process, and the processing is what you want to test? It would seem to me that the most efficient way to get a random entry from a large file is always a worthwhile goal, but I can't tell whether that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, the purpose of the test is not to load that file. Its purpose is to get a random entry without loading the file in every request. The test is what actually happens after I get a random entry.

Comment: Then I'd `fopen` the file, `fseek` to a random location between `0` and the length of the file, read backwards little by little until I found a line break, then `fgets` from there. Should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Why not conisder loading the file in a database or memory? Get a random id and select by primary id?

Comment: There can't be a database involved in this setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fh    = fopen($file, 'r');
$stats = fstat($fh);

// jump to random location within file
fseek($fh, mt_rand(0, $stats['size'] - 1));

// check where you are    
$chr = fread($fh, 1);

// while you're not at a newline and not at the start of the file
while ($chr != "\n" && ftell($fh) > 0) {
    // go back one character (plus an additional one you've just read)
    fseek($fh, -2, SEEK_CUR);
    $chr = fread($fh, 1);
}

// you're just past a newline now, go read the whole next line
$line = fgets($fh);
```